# Chaining verbs with ~て with an object

Tags: て-form, object

In an exercise, the following sentence came out:

(complete the sentence with the propositions in the right order, and say which proposition matches the star)

> 母の誕生日に_____ _____ ***** _____贈った
>
> A. 編んで
>
> B. 心を
>
> C. セーターを
>
> D. 込めて

There's no real doubt about B and D, since 心を込める is a frozen expression.
Also, I'm pretty confident the meaning is "For my mother's birthday, I put my heart into knitting a sweater for her".
So my guess was C, and the sentence was:

> 母の誕生日に心を込めて**セーターを編んで**贈った。

But it comes out that the expected answer was A.
The only structure that makes sense to me is:

> 母の誕生日に心を込めて**編んでセーターを**贈った。

I'm not 100% confident about the source of this exercise, so is this really the right answer?

What bugs me is the fact that the object セーター comes  *after* its verb 編む.
Does Japanese grammar actually allows that?
If so, how frequent is it to say the verb before the object?

Comment: What, they say the answer is A ? It should be a 間違い... 「心を+込めて+編ん**だ** +セーターを」 would be fine...

Comment: What is the source, if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: I just googled it, and I wonder if there's a typo somewhere, either in the author's post, or somehow propagated from the below source into the author's source? I see the sentence 母の誕生日に心を込めて編んだセーターを贈った。which makes sense (to me at least...!) -- see https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GBlhWJk9CyQC&lpg=PA74&ots=4VqLBBhVVw&dq=%E6%AF%8D%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%95%E7%94%9F%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AB%E5%BF%83%E3%82%92%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%E7%B7%A8%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E8%B4%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q&f=false (Ex 58.1)

Comment: It's from japanesetest4you.com: https://japanesetest4you.com/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n3-grammar-exercise-22/ (to see the solution on that website, you have to check an answer for each question, and then you can only know for each question if your answer was right or wrong...) As you can see, it really is 編んで, so I'm a bit perplex here. I mean, sure 編んだセーター would make perfect sense, but セーターを編んで贈った woule be ok too, wouldn't it?

Comment: I also think the correct answer is C.

Comment: Alright, みんなこれは間違いだと思うなら、closeしましょうか?とにかく、ありがとうございました!